# click method throws "Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable"

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to submit a form in this url "http://www.paisabazaar.com/personal-loan" using ruby (watir-webdriver gem) script . I'm able to fill the form using the script but im not able to click on the checkbox and the submit button.

Following are the specifications

chrome=54.0.2840.71
chromedriver=2.25.426923
watir-webdriver (0.9.3, 0.9.1)
ruby version= ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x64-mingw32]
gem version= 2.6.8
OS=windows 7

Script:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
$browser=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
$browser.goto "http://www.paisabazaar.com/personal-loan"
$browser.text_field(:id,'loan_amount').send_keys "400000"
$browser.text_field(:id,'monthly_income').send_keys "90000"
$browser.text_field(:id,'email').send_keys "xyz@domain.com"
$browser.text_field(:id,'mobile_number').send_keys "898989898989"
$browser.button(:id,'submit_first_step').click
```

Error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:389:in `clickElement'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:73:in `click'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:128:in `block in click'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:598:in `element_call'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:117:in `click'
        from (irb):7
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

This error occurs only with the click method (checked in irb). Please check and let me know whats happening and solution for this issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be an unresolved bug in chromedriver. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1388
I recommend adding your reproducible test case there.